# Parallelisation with arrays

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I'm new to this concept, but I heard that there are some sort of thread dangers. That said, how can I code this loop in parallel?

```cs
//OceanVertexIndexes is List<int>
//trisWithVertex is List<int>[]


foreach (int coord in terrainFace.OceanVertexIndexes)
    for (int j = 0; j < trisWithVertex[coord].Count; ++j)//trianglesWith this particular vertex
    {
         int value = trisWithVertex[coord][j];
         int remainder = value % 3;
         trianglesDisabled[value - remainder] = true;
         trianglesDisabled[value - remainder + 1] = true;
         trianglesDisabled[value - remainder + 2] = true;
     }
```

The oceanVertexIndexes is a pretty long enumerable, it has from a few hundreds to a few thousands elements. Also, there is a chance that trianglesDisabled would be accesed at the same time. How should I go about optimising this loop? Spliting it in half? Or is this a case where I can't perform this loop in parallel at all?

```cs
//Should I do it like this?
Parallel.Invoke(/*()=>first half of the oceanVertexIndexes loop, ()=>second half*/);

//Or like this?
        Parallel.ForEach(terrainFace.OceanVertexIndexes, coord =>
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < trisWithVertex[coord].Count; ++j)
            {
                int value = trisWithVertex[coord][j];
                int remainder = value % 3;
                trianglesDisabled[value - remainder] = true;
                trianglesDisabled[value - remainder + 1] = true;
                trianglesDisabled[value - remainder + 2] = true;

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to know the answer to your question without knowing more about your data and your app logic.  Most important: can `trisWithVertex[coord]` contain same values for different values of `coord`?  If yes, then you can have a race condition while accessing `trianglesDisabled`.  But, since you always set `trianglesDisabled` to the same value, `true`, the race condition is a non-issue.  But, again, what happens in the indexer setter of `trianglesDisabled`?  Is it just a simple array, or is it a complex class you implemented, with some logic running every time you change a value?

It is also not clear how much benefit you will get from parallelization.  You need to benchmark your code to be sure.

Comment: 1)trisWithVertex stores all triangles that have that vertex (from a mesh), so no it doesn't contain the same values for different values of coord.2) trianglesDisabled is a simple array of lists. Nothing else happens when you read or write to it.3) Although I didn't benchmark the code, it is clearly needed, because everything is just too slow

Comment: With these clarifications, there is no risk for a race condition.  `Parallel.ForEach` is the preferred option.  Let it do the heavy lifting of partitioning across the available cores.